# JAXB Marshal StringProperty JavaFx

Tags: javafx, binding, jaxb

I am working on a software for processing testcases. I store a single testcase in a xml file on disk.

Now, because its JavaFx I need the StringProperty class for my model to bind my data.

Now I have the inexplicable problem, that I can unmarshal the xml file to my model successfully but I can't marshal the model to an xml file and I get no response of the Jaxb component. He just doesn't create the file.

Let see what I've got:

**Testcase.java (Model)**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Testcase")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Testcase {

private StringProperty Guid;
@XmlElement(name="GUID")
public String getGuid() {
    return guidProperty().get();
}
private StringProperty guidProperty() {
    if (Guid == null)
        Guid = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "Guid");
    return Guid;
}
public void setGuid(String guid) {
    this.guidProperty().set(guid);
}
```

**WrappingFactory.java (Marshall) -- DOESN'T WORK?!**

```
 public boolean MapModelToXmlFile(T model, File destination) {

    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        // output pretty printed
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(model, destination);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return true;
}
```

**WrappingFactory.java (Unmarshall) -- WORKS GREAT**

```
    private T MapXmlFileToModel(String path) {

    File file = new File(path);

    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeParameterClass);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller =  jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        return (T) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

[This picture presents the model after unmarshall.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaBiZ.png)

I read a lot about wrong getters and setters, but I can't find any mistake..

The marshaller worked fine when I used normal String or boolean Properties..

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you see the missing exception-handling in MapModelToXmlFile? Try to add "e.printStackTrace();"

Comment: Oh my god. Thats If you look for hours and hours on your sourcecode and you start to get blind. Thanks. The file is not right.